# Why isn't my custom GNOME launcher showing

Tags: linux, gnome, arch-linux, sublime-text-2

I'm trying to get a launcher to show up on Arch linux with Gnome 3.8 but for some reason it doesn't show up on the menu. I have to strip down the version of the original sublime_text.desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sublime Text
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=sublime-text
Comment=Test message
```

For some reason, no matter what I do it doesn't show up. I tried putting it both in `/usr/share/applications/` and `~/.local/share/applications/` but neither work.

Comment: You may want to try an absolute path to your icon (even though that isn't always necessary).  Also, have you marked it executable (`chmod +x myentry.desktop`)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting permissions to 0777. Didn't work. Good point with the icon but it's trivial as Gnome simply leaves the icon blank if it doesn't find one.

I'm thinking it's more of an issue with Gnome 3.8 or some environment variable not set in Arch's Gnome package.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is due to a wrong or missing command path.
So triple check the command and try using an absolute Path to the Binary.